# How do I use GitLab Community Edition with sha-256 repos?

Tags: git, gitlab, sha256, gitlab-ce

I'm attempting to integrate SHA-256 Git and the GitLab community edition for personal use of SHA-256 repositories (as no real forges support them). I was wondering how GitLab CE sets its hash function because I keep getting a

> fatal: the receiving end does not support this repository's hash algorithm

error when I try to push a SHA-256 Git repo to an existing repository.

I've tried pushing from command-line to existing repos, as well as trying to create an entirely new repo from the command line.

Comment: [This ticket](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/794) was pretty easy to find and gives a very detailed picture on where GitLab is wrt. SHA-256. *tl;dr* it's not done yet and there's no definite timeline.